# How to customize sphinx documentation makefile?

Tags: python, makefile, python-sphinx

I am wondering if there is anyway to customize the sphinx documentation makefile?

What I want to achieve is that each time I do `make html`, sphinx will go to certain directory and copy the specific file to my `source` directory.

---

For example:

Suppose I have a script called name `foo.py` under `~/bar` directory. I want `foo.py` to be copied to `~/docs/source/` directory, which will be referenced by my `project.rst`.

---

The reason I want to do this is that I want to keep the script I referenced in the doc to be the latest version and I hate to do copy-paste each time I do `make html`.

I know I can achieve this purpose with a simple shell script. But, I am wondering if I can do it directly through sphinx make file?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution is to create a symbolic/hard link (`ln -s path/to/destination path/to/link`, remove the `-s` for a hard link).

In your case, `ln -s ~/bar/foo.py ~/docs/source/foo.py` will create a link in the `~/docs/source/` directory (always up-to-date because it is just a link to your original file).

For fancier or more complete Makefile rule, have a look [this customized sphinx Makefile](https://bitbucket.org/lbesson/web-sphinx/src/master/Makefile). There is plenty of rules that send files over the web or from one directory to another (in my case `~/web-sphinx/.build/html/*` to `~/Public/`).